# Array Reverse and sorting is possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to sort names in alphabetical order after a reverse array.

It's a code done for ordering last name/first name in right order.
A few bugs, (like with names with middle names) but it works except the sorting.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $terms = get_terms( 'pa_artist' );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
         echo '<ul class="artists">';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $array = explode(" ", $term->name);
            if ($array[3]) { 
                $array[3] = strtoupper($array[3]);
                $array[3] = "<strong>".$array[3]."</strong>";
            }
            elseif ($array[2]) { 
                $array[2] = strtoupper($array[2]);
                $array[2] = "<strong>".$array[2]."</strong>";
            } elseif ($array[1]) { 
                $array[1] = strtoupper($array[1]);
                $array[1] = "<strong>".$array[1]."</strong>";
            } else { 
                $array[0] = strtoupper($array[0]);
                $array[0] = "<strong>".$array[0]."</strong>";
            } 
            $rarray = array_reverse($array);
           sort($rarray); 
            echo '<li><a href="' .get_term_link( $term ). '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) . '">' . implode(" ", $rarray) . '</a></li>';
        }
     echo '</ul>';
 }
```

For now the names are ordered as if the reverse was never done.

Some examples, at first it showed like this:

```
Auguste Renoir
Pablo Picasso
Paul Gauguin
```

After the reverse and If strings, it's like this:

```
RENOIR Auguste
PICASSO Pablo
GAUGUIN Paul
```

When i need it:

```
GAUGUIN Paul
PICASSO Pablo
RENOIR Auguste
```

I tried every sort fonction, can't make it work… I can't find a way to sort after a reverse array, is it even possible?

It's for a list of names builded with attributes on wordpress/woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand -- it can be done simple like this:

```
$artists = array(
    array('Auguste', '', 'Renoir'),
    array('Pablo', '', 'Picasso'),
    array('Paul', '', 'Gauguin'),
);

usort($artists, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a[2], $b[2]);
});

// print_r($artists);
```

Comment: I gave an example with 3 names, but there is 150+ of them and adding more quite often, can't put each in a string. Would've been easier!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put each individual artist array into a bigger array, and then sort that:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'pa_artist' );
$artists = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $array = explode(" ", $term->name);
    if ($array[3]) { 
        $array[3] = strtoupper($array[3]);
        $array[3] = "<strong>".$array[3]."</strong>";
    }
    elseif ($array[2]) { 
        $array[2] = strtoupper($array[2]);
        $array[2] = "<strong>".$array[2]."</strong>";
    } elseif ($array[1]) { 
        $array[1] = strtoupper($array[1]);
        $array[1] = "<strong>".$array[1]."</strong>";
    } else { 
        $array[0] = strtoupper($array[0]);
        $array[0] = "<strong>".$array[0]."</strong>";
    } 
    $rarray = array_reverse($array);
    $artists[] = $rarray;

}
usort($artists, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a[2], $b[2]);
});

// now run your foreach loop again to output the markup you want...
```

Comment: I tried your code, i understand the logic, i'm sure it's the right way… But can't seem to make it work. :/ @johnnyd23